# RasPi 3B Keeps needing reflash

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

TLDR: My Pi will randomly not boot and need to be reflashed fresh, thus losing my setup.

Hey Guys! So I have a RasPi 3 that I have been able to flash the OS to. I'm typing this on my Pi 3 now actually.

So I use this primarily as my programming CPU. I can VNC or SSH in while I'm learning Python. I hate Windows for programming but need to keep it, and would rather not dual boot.

My problem is: Randomly, the OS won't boot and I have to reflash, losing everything. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to protect it from that? Maybe create a new user with less permissions?

I don't do anything too crazy. Mostly Git stuff and programming.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: I agree with joan's comments **BUT** "thus losing my setup" - why don't you make a backup?

Comment: When it doesn't boot, does that mean that the green light doesn't turn on at all?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to see how we can help.

You need to find out why it will not boot.  Perhaps look at this [boot sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

If you are only using standard Raspbian software from the Raspbian repositories you should not have problems.  If that's the case that indicates a dodgy SD card.  Buy a new one from a reputable supplier.

If you are downloading software from other sources then stop doing so until you have ruled out that software as the likely problem.

Comment: So I'm able to boot a clean flash. And as I do work or apt-get, it'll randomly just not boot anymore. I've tried different cards and USBs. All from reputable. Even tried on the 3 different Pi's I own. I'm not the greatest at Linux yet, maybe that's my issue

Comment: Also, I never thought to backup my pi. I have no idea why.

Comment: Dodgy USB cable.  Have you worked through the boot sticky and checked every point?

Comment: And you do a clean shutdown `sudo poweroff` before you power off your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes, i did go through the sticky. 

I don't use a cable. I just plug the USB directly into the PI. 

I've downloaded the Deja-Dup and going to backup to a thumbdrive going forward.

Comment: @rathor1622 "I don't use a cable. I just plug the USB directly into the PI" - I find that hard to believe, I have never seen a power supply which could be used without a cable.